# Normalization of convolution kernel

Tags: python, kernel-smoothing, convolution, numpy

I am trying to smooth a noisy one-dimensional physical signal, `y`, while retaining correspondence between the signal's amplitude and its units. I'm applying a Gaussian kernel and normalizing the Gaussian itself without doing so with respect to the physical axis of my signal, `y`.

```
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

#Gaussian kernel (not normalized here)
def gaussian(x, sigma):
    return np.exp(-(x/sigma)**2/2) 

#convolution
def smooth(y,box_pts): 
    x = (np.linspace(-box_pts/2.,box_pts/2.,box_pts + 1)) #Gaussian centred on 0
    std_norm = 3. #3. is an arbitrary value for normalizing the sigma
    sigma = box_pts/std_norm 
    integral = quad(gaussian, x[0], x[-1], args=(sigma))[0]
    box = gaussian(x, sigma)/integral
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y,box,mode='same')
    return y_smooth

box_size = 10
length = 100
y = numpy.random.randn(length)
y_smooth = smooth(y,box_size)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
plt.plot(y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

In this example, `y` is the signal I want to smooth, `box_pts` is the width or region over which the Gaussian kernel is applied as it is translated. And to normalize my convolution, I've simply divided by the integral of the Gaussian by itself. Since the Gaussian has a certain width (given by `box_pts`) and is zero outside of this interval compared to the physical axis of `y`, I am normalizing the Gaussian to the region over which it is non-zero as opposed to $-\infty$ to $ \infty$. This method appears simple enough and the normalization appears to work, but is dividing by the kernel's integral itself the "right"  or suggested approach to take when normalizing convolutions/kernels?

Based on a simple example, it appears keep the integral about the same, but amplitudes are no longer consistent as visualized below which is a bit problematic as I want to retain a smoothed signal while removing the noise:

Original:

[image: Raw data]

Smoothed:

[image: Smoothed data]

I get improved amplitudes when I decrease `box_size` relative to `length`, but this keeps the signal noisy. Decreasing `std_norm` also appears to help reduce noise, but this influences the amplitude. My question boils down to deciding how one chooses optimal `std_norm` and `box_norm` for a given noisy signal `y` of size `length` such that I can reduce the noise while keeping the output physically sound (i.e. smoothed signal amplitude is somewhat consistent with the original signal and the integral under the smoothed curve is fairly similar, too).